# Why jpa manyToOne lazy fetch is unavailable, it still lead to useless Association query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

```
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"bmsPost"})
    @ManyToOne(optional = true,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private  UmsUser umsUser;
```

```
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"umsUser"})
    @Column(name = "create_time", nullable = false)
    private Date createTime;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "umsUser",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
//    @JoinColumn(name="user_id",referencedColumnName="id")
private List<BmsPost> bmsPost;
```

I just want to select BmsPost, but it selects BmsPost and UmsUser

```
    List<BmsPost> findAllByTitle(String title);
```

Result:

```
Hibernate: select bmspost0_.id as id1_1_, bmspost0_.collects as collects2_1_, bmspost0_.comments as comments3_1_, bmspost0_.content as content4_1_, bmspost0_.create_time as create_t5_1_, bmspost0_.essence as essence6_1_, bmspost0_.modify_time as modify_t7_1_, bmspost0_.section_id as section_8_1_, bmspost0_.title as title9_1_, bmspost0_.top as top10_1_, bmspost0_.user_id as user_id11_1_, bmspost0_.view as view12_1_ from bms_post bmspost0_ where bmspost0_.title=?
Hibernate: select umsuser0_.id as id1_3_0_, umsuser0_.active as active2_3_0_, umsuser0_.alias as alias3_3_0_, umsuser0_.avatar as avatar4_3_0_, umsuser0_.bio as bio5_3_0_, umsuser0_.create_time as create_t6_3_0_, umsuser0_.email as email7_3_0_, umsuser0_.mobile as mobile8_3_0_, umsuser0_.modify_time as modify_t9_3_0_, umsuser0_.password as passwor10_3_0_, umsuser0_.role_id as role_id11_3_0_, umsuser0_.score as score12_3_0_, umsuser0_.status as status13_3_0_, umsuser0_.token as token14_3_0_, umsuser0_.username as usernam15_3_0_ from ums_user umsuser0_ where umsuser0_.id=?
[BmsPost{id='1408691924814835713', title='ds', content='dsd', userId='1349618748226658305', comments=0, collects=0, view=0,top=false, essence=false, sectionId=0, createTime=2021-06-26 15:41:42.0,modifyTime=null, umsUser=com.example.demo.Entity.UmsUser@38d115a4}]
```

How to avoid it?

Comment: Can you show us the BmsPost  entity code?

Comment: [This is a link to BmsPost](https://gist.github.com/edcjian/90de353a0f60cc2babab9f97d9413a9f)

Comment: [This is a link to  UmsUser](https://gist.github.com/edcjian/e6a01ff3fa67db1e8755291131d1771f)

Comment: This is weird indeed as the relationship is set as Lazy. It should not trigger the second select.

Comment: i  delete toString(),Actually solved the problem,why?

Answer (score 0):

Do you define List bmsPost in your DTO?
if you define that property in your DTO when you get your Data from DB Hibernate create a query for them to get data it needs